# RNN where features are sequences with different lengths

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

I have a sequential RNN using Keras. Some of my features are sequences with different lengths (eg time series where data is collected daily or monthly) and some other features are scalars. Would this create a problem or do all features need to be of same length by using padding or some other method?